# wsl2 randomly starts highlighting everything I type in pink

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am not sure what causes this, but whenever I open up the wsl2 terminal, things are normal. But randomly, wsl2 will just start highlighting everything that I type in pink. Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I haven't seen this (I don't think), but this is probably a post where adding a screenshot would be really helpful.  Folks might recognize what's going on better visually.

Comment: Also, you really don't mention Ubuntu here in the issue, and questions here really do have to be about Ubuntu.  What Ubuntu release are you using?  Does it happen when you are running any particular application?  You might also want to try a different WSL distribution to try to isolate the problem - It could be in the terminal, WSL, Ubuntu, or even an application.  Thanks!

Comment: I can add a screenshot later when I am on my work computer. But I really cant find a reason why it starts. I just happens randomly and then if I enter `clear`, it stops.